# How to prevent asp.net MVC from caching some sections such as login username

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, razor

I have the following action method, that cache the output on the server:-

```
[CheckUserPermissions(Action = "", Model = "Admin")]
       [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "short", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server, VaryByHeader = "X-Requested-With")]
       public ActionResult SystemInfo(int page = 1,bool forTechAudit=false)
       {
```

And on my _layout shared view I am showing the current logined user as follow:-

```
<span class="username customTopNavText " style=" display:block; "><i class="icon-user"></i><strong > @User.Identity.Name.Substring(User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1)</strong></span>
```

But the problem I am facing is that when userA access the action method , his username will be cached as part of the returned view. and when userB access the cached data userA username will be displayed on userB browser. So is there a way to prevent caching the username  inside my _layout shared view??
Thanks

**EDIT**

i have installed the DonutCachint from nuget , then i added the following to the layout view `Html.Action("getuser","Home",true)`. and i defined the following action method :-

```
public string getuser() 
{
            return User.Identity.Name.Substring(User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
        }
```

but still the user name is being cached. any idea what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

If you did not want to alter your page structure, you could pass a param containing the userid, and use the [VaryByParam](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.outputcacheparameters.varybyparam%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

[OutputCache(VaryByParam="UserId")]

Alternatively, you could create your own implementation of a [VaryByCustom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.outputcacheparameters.varybycustom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and have some serverside way of looking up the User. Adopted from [here](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/ssmith/archive/2007/10/29/VaryByCustom-Caching-By-User.aspx)

[OutputCache(VaryByCustom="userName")]

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
{
    if (arg == "userName")
    {
        return context.User.Identity.Name;
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

There are some different techniques known as donut caching, whereas you cache the outer page layout and not some inner partial content of the page (the donut hole).  The story here gets more complicated, but you can read further [here](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/donut-output-caching-in-asp.net-mvc-3).

As you point out, this is probably the better option if you did not have a high hit ratio by user and did not require the user specific data to be cached.

Comment: i do not want to pass UserId as i will be caching separate version of the data for each user, which will not be feasible !!..

Comment: You probably want to look into donut caching to avoid this

Comment: but where is should add <%@ OutputCache Duration="99999" VaryByParam="*" VaryByCustom="userName" %> . and hwo i will be passing this to the view

Comment: that is aspx webforms code, MVC handles this via the OutputCacheAttribute ... i altered my post to show the MVC version of this.  But as you point out, this is going to cache content per user... which might not be what you want to do if you do not have a high hit ratio by user or have a ton of unique users.

Comment: yes of course i do not want to cache per user.. so what other options i can follow?

Comment: Checkout the [MvcDonutCaching](https://github.com/moonpyk/mvcdonutcaching/blob/master/README.md) project, sample usage of the nuget package [here](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/ODJa210113-Donut-Caching-and-Donut-Hole-Caching-with-Asp.Net-MVC-4.html)